# ¿Como puedo hacer el min y max de 5 años ion-datetime?

Tags: ionic

Tengo un ion-datetime para mostrar el año. Ejemplo: año 2017 maximo 5 años por encima y 5 años por debajo del año actual.

Estoy utilizando 
Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 6.4.0 
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-rc.2
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.8
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.4
Ionic App Scripts Version: 0.0.43
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: Linux 4.8
Node Version: v6.5.0
Xcode version: Not installed

Answer (score 0):

Hola¡ mirando la documentación podemos ver que se puede configurar el MIN y el MAX de esta forma para la versión 2 de Ionic:

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Date</ion-label>
  <ion-datetime displayFormat="MMMM YYYY" min="2016" max="2020-10-31" [(ngModel)]="myDate">
  </ion-datetime>
</ion-item>
```

Para Ionic 1 no existe este componente, pero puedes utilizar HTML5, de esta manera y añadirle MIN y MAX:

```
    <label class="item item-input">
        <span class="input-label">Date</span>
        <input type="date" min="{{min}}" max="{{max}}">
    </label>
```

Puedes calcular automática el MIN y el MAX con la librería [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/) de esta manera:

```
$scope.myDate = new Date();

$scope.min = moment();
$scope.max = moment();

//SUMAR 5 AÑOS
$scope.max.add(5, 'years');

//RESTAR 5 AÑOS
$scope.min.subtract(5, 'years');
```

Espero que te sirva, ya nos cuentas